# SELECT unique groups

Tags: sql, select, group-by, union

I have a Table with values like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        USER         |        ITEM      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Abel         |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Abel         |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Bart         |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Bart         |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Curt         |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Curt         |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Dawn         |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Emma         |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Emma         |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Emma         |         7        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Fina         |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

From that table I want to select only the ones that not follow:

1. USERS can only have one item by themselves.
2. USERS can have more than one ITEM only if they have it with another USER.
3. A group of USERS can have only one ITEM in common.

Following that:

- **Fina** has only **1 ITEM**, she's **OK** and she shouldn't be included.
- **Emma** has **3 ITEMS**, but two of them are shared with different USERS so she's **OK** and she shouldn't be included.
- **Dawn** has only **1 ITEM**, she's **OK** and she shouldn't be included.
- **Curt has **2 ITEMS**, he is **NOT OK** and he should be included
- **Bart** and **Abel** have 2 items in common, they are **NOT OK** and they should be included.

Is this possible with SQL or I need to make a script it in another language?

At least I need to know the COUNT of users that are NOT OK

Best case scenario, a table with a list of **items** that are *wrong*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For users that have more than one item, you can use window functions:

```
select user
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by item) as item_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where item_cnt = 1
group by user
having count(*) >= 2;
```

For users that share more than one item with another user, you can use a self-join:

```
select distinct t1.user
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.item = t2.item and t1.user <> t2.user
group by t1.user, t2.user
having count(*) > 1;
```

The final solution is the `union` of these two queries.